# Should "Thanks for your edit!" message include a link to the review page?

Tags: feature-request, edits, review, suggested-edits

Currently when a user submits a suggested edit, this message appears at the top of the edited post:

> #### Thanks for your edit!
>
> This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

I suggest the words *peer reviewed* provide a hyperlink to the corresponding review page, where the user can see the diff, and eventually who is approving or rejecting their suggested edit.

Currently, a user that doesn't have access to the "Review" section can only see this by accessing their user profile and looking up their suggested edit in their "Activity" history... which is somewhat asking a lot to new StackExchange users.

This feature should be implemented on all SE sites, as it would contribute to make common site features more easily discoverable to newcomers.

Comment: Or should I have posted this on Meta.StackOverflow?

Comment: Yeah, this is more appropriate for MSO since it's an SE-wide thing.